# Retrieve zipped dependency from ivy using gradle

Tags: android, gradle, ivy

I'm starting moving my Android project to Gradle build system, and struggling with my dependencies. I was using Ant and Ivy before, and one particular problem keeps me from going forward.

This is what I have now in `ivy.xml`:

```
<dependency org="com.my-org" name="my-dep" rev="1.0.+">
    <artifact name="my-dep-sdk" type="jar" ext="zip" />
</dependency>
```

As you can see, this is a zipped dependency. Zip file contains jar and a directory with native libraries, both should be unpacked in the same directory. Ivy works fine, but I can't reproduce same behavior with Gradle. Any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

For direct download You can try this:

ivy-setting.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="central">
            ...
            <url name="google_download" m2compatible="true">
                <artifact pattern="[url]"/>
            </url>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>

</ivysettings>
```

ivy.xml:

```
 <ivy-module>   
      <dependencies>        

       <dependency name="jdbf" rev="1.2" url="jar:https://jdbf.googlecode.com/files/jdbf-1.2-all.zip!/dist/jdbf-1.2.jar" />

      </dependencies>    
 </ivy-module>
```

Comment: But your answer is about how to do it in Ivy, not in Gradle, right? I have it done in Ivy, now I need the Gradle version.